# React 18 and Pixijs 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, pixi.js

I am currently trying to use Pixi 7 with a react-dom 18 frontend. I need to add / remove multiple canvases dynamically within a single page application. I have not figured out a way to even get "normal" pixi.js to work.

I do not want to build with the pixi/react module (as this is only a subset of pixi). What I need is the full Pixi. Is there a way to do this? Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Application, Sprite, Texture, Container } from 'pixi.js';


class Unit extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="stage"></div>
        );
    }

        componentDidMount() {
            const app = new Application({
                view: document.getElementById("stage"),
                resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
                autoDensity: true,
                backgroundColor: 0x6495ed,
                width: 640,
                height: 480
            });

            const conty = new Container();
            conty.x = 200;
            conty.y = 0;
            app.stage.addChild(conty);
            
            const clampy = Sprite.from("clampy.png");
            clampy.x = 100;
            clampy.y = 100;
            conty.addChild(clampy);

        }
}




export default Unit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of getting pixi and react to work properly. It works with Pixi 7.1.4 and react 18. Also it works in React.StrictMode which renders components twice in developer mode:

```
class PixiExample extends React.Component {
  pixiApp = null; // reference to pixi application
  canvasRef = React.createRef(); // reference to DOM

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // init pixi application once!!
    if (!this.pixiApp) {
      this.pixiApp = new PIXI.Application({
        backgroundColor: 0x3495ed,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
      });

      const clampy = PIXI.Sprite.from("https://pixijs.io/pixi-react/img/bunny.png");
      clampy.x = this.pixiApp.screen.width / 2;
      clampy.y = this.pixiApp.screen.height / 2;

      this.pixiApp.stage.addChild(clampy);
      console.log(this.ref);
    
      // add to the DOM
      this.canvasRef.current.appendChild(this.pixiApp.view);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // cleanup
    if (this.pixiApp) {
      this.pixiApp.stop(); // stop the renderer
      this.pixiApp.destroy(true); // remove pixi and the canvas
      this.pixiApp = null; // cleanup refernce to pixi
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.canvasRef} />;
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<PixiExample />);
```

Please find a working [codepen example here](https://codepen.io/stot/pen/VwGyoVY?editors=0010)